# Dividing a particular numeric column by maximum observation corresponding to another factor column

Tags: r

I am working on a data set baseball in R in a package plyr.

```
require(plyr)
head(baseball[,c(1,2,6:12)], n=7)

           id year  g  ab  r  h X2b X3b hr
4   ansonca01 1871 25 120 29 39  11   3  0
44  forceda01 1871 32 162 45 45   9   4  0
68  mathebo01 1871 19  89 15 24   3   1  0
99  startjo01 1871 33 161 35 58   5   1  1
102 suttoez01 1871 29 128 35 45   3   7  3
106 whitede01 1871 29 146 40 47   6   5  1
113  yorkto01 1871 29 145 36 37   5   7  2
```

I am interested in dividing the value of variables g through hr (variables 6 through 12) in baseball by the maximum of each of those columns for each year (1871-2007).

For example, year 1871, maximum for variable g=33

So all the values of g falling under year 1871 will be divided by 33.

year 1872, maximum for variable g=55

So all the values of g falling under year 1872 will be divided by 55.

tapply(g,year,max)

I tried tapply to get maximum of of variables with respect to variable year. But how to divide the value of variables g through hr (variables 6 through 12) in baseball by the maximum of each of those columns for each year (1871-2007), i am not getting. please help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` options.  Grouped by 'year', use `mutate_at` to select the columns of interest and divide each element of the columns by the `max` of that column

```
library(dplyr)
data(baseball, package = "plyr")
baseball %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(g:hr), ~ ./max(., na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 21,699 x 22
# Groups:   year [137]
#   id         year stint team  lg        g    ab     r     h   X2b   X3b    hr   rbi    sb    cs    bb    so   ibb   hbp    sh    sf  gidp
#   <chr>     <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 ansonca01  1871     1 RC1   ""    0.758 0.741 0.644 0.672 1     0.429 0        16     6     2     2     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2 forceda01  1871     1 WS3   ""    0.970 1     1     0.776 0.818 0.571 0        29     8     0     4     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3 mathebo01  1871     1 FW1   ""    0.576 0.549 0.333 0.414 0.273 0.143 0        10     2     1     2     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 4 startjo01  1871     1 NY2   ""    1     0.994 0.778 1     0.455 0.143 0.333    34     4     2     3     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5 suttoez01  1871     1 CL1   ""    0.879 0.790 0.778 0.776 0.273 1     1        23     3     1     1     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6 whitede01  1871     1 CL1   ""    0.879 0.901 0.889 0.810 0.545 0.714 0.333    21     2     2     4     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 7 yorkto01   1871     1 TRO   ""    0.879 0.895 0.8   0.638 0.455 1     0.667    23     2     2     9     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 8 ansonca01  1872     1 PH1   ""    0.836 0.770 0.909 1     0.909 1     0        50     6     6    16     3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 9 burdoja01  1872     1 BR2   ""    0.673 0.617 0.394 0.511 0.273 0     0        15     0     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#10 forceda01  1872     1 TRO   ""    0.455 0.461 0.606 0.589 1     0     0        16     2     2     1     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# … with 21,689 more rows
```

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(baseball)[6:12]
as.data.table(baseball)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x)
         x/max(x, na.rm = TRUE)), .SDcols =nm1, by = .(year)][]
```

Comment: Shows this error in R markdown:    processing file: file.Rmd
Quitting from lines 8-80 (file.Rmd) 
Error in baseball2 %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate_at(vars(g:hr), ~./max(.,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

Execution halted

Comment: @BilalPara. I am not getting any error with the example showed

Comment: @BilalPara. If the error is R markdown, that is a different issue